# How to read specific line in python and print data to text file or console window?

Tags: python, parsing

I'm trying to parse lines from a text file, and print the data values found in them. I need to print the "DeltaE" and the "Intensity" from each line

My code so far :

```
if ('Duschinsky Tranformation' or 'Calculations of Band Intensities') \
    in line:
    while not 'DeltaE = ' in line:
        line = next(inputfile)
deltae = float(line.split()[0])
```

Text file i am reading:

```
 ==================================================
             Duschinsky Transformation
 ==================================================

 ==================================================
          Calculations of Band Intensities
 ==================================================

  Energy of the 0-0 transition:  14394.5813 cm^(-1)


 Notes about the overlap integrals description:
 - DeltaE is the relative energy of the transition (wrt 0-0)
 - TDMI^2 is the square of the transition dipole moment integral
 - Intensity is the line intensity

-- To: vibronic fundamental state --

Initial state: <0|
Final state: |0>
  DeltaE =     0.0000 | TDMI^2 =  5.657    , Intensity = 0.5604E+06
 ........................................
 --------------------
++ Spectrum progression:   68.60%

-- To: single overtones --

Initial state: <0|
Final state: |1^1>
  DeltaE =    13.5423 | TDMI^2 = 0.6670E-01, Intensity =  6553.    
 ........................................
Initial state: <0|
Final state: |2^1>
  DeltaE =    17.9918 | TDMI^2 = 0.2693    , Intensity = 0.2668E+05
 ........................................
Initial state: <0|
Final state: |3^1>
  DeltaE =    22.4523 | TDMI^2 = 0.4740E-01, Intensity =  4644.    
 ........................................
Initial state: <0|
Final state: |5^1>
  DeltaE =    26.5963 | TDMI^2 = 0.1649E-01, Intensity =  1633.
```

I need to read DeltaE and Intensity as array. And write them to txt file by 2 separate columns. Like that

```
  13.5423      6553
  17.9918      0.2668E+05
```

and etc.
Also if you want to see some examples I am using you can download parser file 
http://www.filedropper.com/gaussianparser

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. What currently works? What doesn't currently work?

Comment: I am new to python srrr for that , i just dont know if i done correct choosing line, and dont know how to print them in array  like i said at the end. I am just trying to do something by googling but nothing is working :(

Comment: You don't need to apologise for being new to a language (everyone was new once) - but read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and think about how you can structure your question better to make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Ok to sum up i just need to read that specific data and print in 2 columns like i showed at the end :)

Comment: First column stands for DeltaE and second for Intensity

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33746746/parsing-files-via-python-using-cclib-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

handy python commands to learn:  split, strip, and string slicing

```
for line in inputfile:
  line = line.strip() #remove whitespace before and after
  if line[0:6] == 'DeltaE':
    #then we have a line like: DeltaE =    13.5423 | TDMI^2 = 0.6670E-01, Intensity =  6553.
    deltae = float(line.split('|')[0].strip().split('=')[1].strip())
    intensity = float(line.split('|')[1].strip().split(',')[1].strip().split('=')[1].strip())

    print deltae, ',', intensity
```

you can also experiment with replacing all spaces with '' prior to splitting.
to get a better understanding of what is going on, we can look at the line:

```
    deltae = float(line.split('|')[0].strip().split('=')[1].strip())
```

and break it up...

```
    temp = line.split('|')[0].strip() #temp="DeltaE =    13.5423"
    temp = temp.split('=')[1].strip() #temp is now "13.5423"
    deltae = float(temp) #convert string to float.
```

try doing the same with intensity.

Comment: if line [0:5]   srr but i dont get it what is it ?

Comment: sorry, I think it should have been line[0:6]  try print line[0:6] and you'll see what it is.  it takes the first 6 characters in the string line. google "python string slicing"

Comment: Maybe you know how to read form that specific line ?  Because my ouput file is very huge , here i showed only a part which i need to read .

Comment: iterating by line on a huge file still works.  my suggestion would be to get some code *working* on a small version and then figure out where things break(or become slow) as the file gets bigger. once you figure out where the problem is, you can describe it in an other SO post. generally, if you can articulate one problem per post, your responses are more effective.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to parse that "un-structured" file is through regular expressions.

You can use [regex101](https://regex101.com/#python) to learn the basics.

A regex like this should work to match group1 and group2 for your values:

```
           Group 1                           Group 2
             |                                 |
DeltaE =.*\s(.*) [|] TDMI\^2 =.*Intensity =.* (.*\d)
```

And then write it to output.txt file.

python code like this should work:

```
import re

expr = re.compile(r'DeltaE =.*\s(.*) [|] .*Intensity =.* (.*\d)')
with open("file.txt") as input_file:
    with open("output.txt", 'w') as out:
        for line in input_file:
            m = expr.search(line)
            if m:
                out.write('\t'.join([m.group(1), m.group(2), '\n']))
```

Comment: I cant rewrite output file because its calculated gaussian file form quantum chemistry, and i am using cclib to parse that output file to get info about molecule charges, bonds and etc. but that cclib do not print DeltaE so somehow i must figure this out and add some code to the existing parser

Comment: I thought you wanted to write the output to a file. (That's what you asked on your post)

Comment: I need to write it, but the point is that i need to read output.txt file and then write other like test.txt where those 2 colums apears from output.txt. So my first goal would be to clearly read these data and later somehow print them to txt file or window

Comment: @PanGalactic got there slightly before my answer, but I've left my answer as it uses a slightly different approach with the regex, In particular it allows for variable numbers of spaces in more parts of the regex.

Comment: @user5568235 then you have to replace file.txt to output.txt and output.txt to test.txt on the above code.

Answer (score 0):

This example would be fantastic for regular expressions as well. If you're not familiar with regular expressions, then they're worth reading about as they can avoid a lot of the stripping, splitting and slicing in @user1269942 answer (although that is a very good answer to this problem)

I have omitted the first part, the if statement which checks for the file's title. the code below only finds lines which contain a DeltaE and Intesity

```
import re

for line in text.splitlines():
    m = re.match("\s*DeltaE\s*=\s*([0-9.E+-]+).*Intensity\s*=\s*([0-9.E+-]+)", line)
    if m != None:
            print (m.group(1), m.group(2))
```

The regular expression is pretty scary when you first look at it, however it is a single expression which defines the entire content of the line.

Let's break down the expression

```
\s*DeltaE\s*=\s*([0-9.E+-]+).*Intensity\s*=\s*([0-9.E+-]+)
```

- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace characters (`\s` means a single whitespace character, `*` is a multiplier which says '0 or more times'
- `DeltaE` - the string "DeltaE" exactly once
- `\s*` - whitespace again
- `=` - the equals sign exactly once
- `\s*` - whitespace again
- `([0-9.E+-]+)` - This section matches any string of characters which appear inside the square brackets, and `+` means there must be 1 or more of them. `0-9` is a shortcut for `0123456789` and with the other characters we can find most things that look like a decimal or scientific notation number. By putting this in round brackets we allow ourselves to collect the value later as a 'group'.
- `.*` - any string (we use this to avoid having to have a complex regex for the middle section - `.` is a single character which can be anything, `*` means 0 or more times as before)
- `Intensity` - the string "Intesity" exactly once
- `\s*` - whitespace again
- `=` - the equals sign exactly once
- `\s*` - whitespace again
- `([0-9.E+-]+)` - This is a number again, captured in a second 'group' by the round brackets.

Having created the expression, we can match it to the line (`re.match`), if it doesn't match then the our variable `m` will be `None`, otherwise we have a match.

`if m != None` then we have a match and we can then use `m.group(1)` to get the value matching the first set of round brackets and `m.group(2)` to get the second. We then use print to print them out.

Comment: Sorry for dumb question but for line in text(here i must define my output.txt?)

Comment: you will need to change this loop to iterate over the lines in your file, there are several ways of doing this - one is to load the whole file into one string (as I have done), alternatively, you could iterate directly over the lines in the file while reading it

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/bchla-ccd-vibronic-fc-01, here is my full output.log i am parsing , what i want to say that i have thousands of these files , names are different but arrangement the same , and i need that certain part of data to read, i cant rename all files by hand, Srr if i dont understood something.

Comment: You're starting to ask a very different question. I suggest you post it as a seperate question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33746746/parsing-files-via-python-using-cclib-library maybe this is more specific ? what you think about that ?